# .NET REST 'GET' call returns json data but returns null in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-chrome, firefox

I have a function in my angular code that makes a REST GET call to the server. in Fiddler the data is returned with a 200 and the object is returned in IE and Edge, but the data is returned as null in Chrome and Firefox, here is my code.

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:62012/api/Restaurants').success(function (response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
}).error(function (err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
})
```

Comment: Did you test the API via POSTMAN?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin No I have never used that before.

Comment: You can use POSTMAN to test your RESTful API. It's a chrome tool, you can download it and test your API.

Comment: I tested it and it comes back 200 just like in fiddler. the data is returned as null only in firefox and chrome @ShaohaoLin

Comment: Can you create a plunker link then? This problem seems wired to me.

Comment: I second that, plunkr or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: I found that this article fixed the problem for me, I am using two different projects in visual studio one for the backend WebAPI and one for the Client-Side. For this to work with angular you need to enable CORS http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En#enablecors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this article fixed the problem for me, I am using two different projects in visual studio one for the backend WebAPI and one for the Client-Side. For this to work with angular you need to enable CORS http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En#enablecors

This code should be put into you app.js folder

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    // Override $http service's default transformRequest
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
        /**
         * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
         * @param {Object} obj
         * @return {String}
         */
        var param = function (obj) {
            var query = '';
            var name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
            for (name in obj) {
                value = obj[name];
                if (value instanceof Array) {
                    for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                        subValue = value[i];
                        fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                        innerObj = {};
                        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                    }
                }
                else if (value instanceof Object) {
                    for (subName in value) {
                        subValue = value[subName];
                        fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                        innerObj = {};
                        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                    }
                }
                else if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
                    query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
                }
            }
            return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
        };
        return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
    }];
```

and this should be put into you WebApiConfig.cs file

```
//Web API CORS
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```